# docker-compose up giving error

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have folder structure like below

```
.
├── docker-compose.yml
└── web-app
    ├── create_tomcat_admin.sh
    ├── Dockerfile
    ├── pom.xml
    └── run.sh
```

And my `docker-compose.yml` is like

```
version: '3'
services:
  web-app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: web-app/Dockerfile
    ports:
       - 8080:8080
    network_mode: "host"
```

Once i execute `docker-compose build` it executes perfectly and in terminal it shows like below

```
Step 10/15 : ADD /web-app/create_tomcat_admin_user.sh /create_tomcat_admin_user.sh
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6ca9922b3628
 Step 11/15 : ADD /web-app/run.sh /run.sh
  ---> Using cache
  ---> c1e843f2f67a
 Step 12/15 : RUN chmod +x /*.sh
  ---> Using cache
  ---> 6b8e781b830c
 Step 13/15 : COPY /web-app/target/*.war /tomcat/webapps
  ---> Using cache
  ---> fc046d9d1d3e
 Step 14/15 : EXPOSE 8080
  ---> Using cache
  ---> 68f788c21a84
 Step 15/15 : CMD /run.sh
  ---> Using cache
  ---> d88cc5594980
 Successfully built d88cc5594980
 Successfully tagged opt_web-app:latest`
```

after building docker-compose, when i execute `docker-compose up` it is giving error

```
 ben@ubuntu:~/Desktop/opt$ docker-compose up
 Starting opt_web-app_1
 Attaching to opt_web-app_1
 web-app_1  | standard_init_linux.go:187: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
 opt_web-app_1 exited with code 1
 ben@ubuntu:~/Desktop/opt$
```

Where i am going wrong? But error should be displayed while building `docker-compose.yml` right?

Comment: You might have been able to **build** the image correctly, but **running** the image may be causing error.

Comment: Past the run.sh script. Building and running are to different step. If you provide a command that is not available in your container, build will be ok, but not running.

Comment: This is my [Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/Beanben/f21d317b926459a0164eff9e9c7e362a) which i am using.

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this. In another `Ubuntu 16` machine with the same folder structure its working fine without any errors.

Comment: That error message is not helpful - docker need to improve it.  Looking around the web I see a number of people get it when they've used Windows line endings - they use dos2unix to fix it.  I'm getting it for a different reason, but same unhelpful error message.  I have a three line Dockerfile with the CMD starting a Rust binary directly, no .sh script.  There should be a way to dig around to debug this.

Comment: @10 cls: Are you basing off Alpine Linux by any chance? One possibility is your binary needs to be recompiled for uclibc or is missing another required dynamically linked library https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/14972

Comment: This might be a dumb question, but have you tried `CMD ./run.sh` instead of `CMD /run.sh`?

Answer (score -1):

I had the same unhelpful error when I tried to run docker-compose on Windows from a project I created in Linux. If you clone a Linux project on Windows, by default Git adds Windows style line endings which mess up any Bash scripts. If this is the case run `git config --global core.autocrlf false` to configure Git to never change the line endings. Then delete repository and re-clone it.

Alternatively if you created the project initially on Windows, many times the IDE adds Windows style line endings. If this is the case then in Notepad++, Click edit menu > EOL Conversion > Unix.